# Writing XML in C# from defined schema

Tags: c#, xml

I'm creating an XML from a defined schema I need to follow.

This is my code:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(desktopPath + "\fatt.xml", settings))
{
  writer.WriteStartDocument();

  #region FatturaElettronicaHeader 1

  writer.WriteStartElement("FatturaElettronicaHeader");

  #region DatiTrasmissione 1.1
  writer.WriteStartElement("DatiTrasmissione"); 

  var statoAnag = statiRep.GetId(anagraficoCliente.stato); 

  writer.WriteStartElement("IdTrasmittente"); 
  writer.WriteElementString("IdPaese",statoAnag.codice_iso); 
  writer.WriteElementString("IdCodice",anagraficoCliente.codice_fiscale); 
  writer.WriteEndElement();

  writer.WriteElementString("ProgressivoInvio", "0");
  writer.WriteElementString("FormatoTrasmissione",FORMATO_TRASMISSIONE); 

  writer.WriteElementString("CodiceDestinatario",codiceSdi); 

  writer.WriteElementString("PECDestinatario","prova@pec.it"); 
  writer.WriteEndElement();

  #endregion DatiTrasmissione 1.1

  #region 2
  ....
  #endregion 2

  writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Basically I just have to read data from my db and then put in a xml file.

It works fine but I think is not really readable even if I used a lot of region to tidy up code.

What can I do to improve my code ? If there's any

Comment: I think you shouldn't have removed any code but you definitely should have included the schema of the xml and the models you are converting to it.

Comment: When you say "schema" do you mean that you have an XSD document, a DTD, some other designed-for-automation document, or a textual description?

Comment: I do have an XSD.

Answer (score 1):

When I had to create an XML file for one of my projects, I basically created a class for each element and passed along a class that contained all the data I needed to use in the XML.

It started with this class:

```
internal sealed class XmlCreator
{
    public static XElement Execute(RequestConfig requestConfig)
    {
        return ImportElementCreator.Execute(requestConfig);
    }
}
```

Which in turn used this class:

```
internal sealed class ImportElementCreator
{
    public static XElement Execute(RequestConfig requestConfig)
    {
        var element = new XElement("Import");

        element.Add(PersElementCreator.Execute(requestConfig));

        return element;
    }
}
```

etc etc etc. I'm sure you get the point.

Part of the reason was that the resulting XML file could differ, depending on the action in the request: an "Update" required more data than a "Delete", and thus some classes contained some logic:

```
    public static XElement Execute(RequestConfig requestConfig)
    {
        var element = new XElement("Access-Rule",
            new XAttribute("id", requestConfig.Position ?? 1), 
            new XAttribute("operation", requestConfig.RequestType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
            );

        if (requestConfig.RequestType != RequestType.Update)
        {
            return element;
        }

        element.Add(RuleElementCreator.Execute(requestConfig.AccessRuleId));

        element.Add(StartDateElementCreator.Execute(requestConfig.StartDate));

        element.Add(EndDateElementCreator.Execute(requestConfig.EndDate));

        return element;
    }
```

The downside is that you might end up with a lot of small classes if you have a complicated XML file, and that you need to look out for duplicate class names.

---

Of course, if you look at `XmlCreator`, you end up with an `XElement`, not an XML file.

To actually write the XML file, I had this:

```
internal sealed class FileWriter
{
    private readonly string _localDirectory;
    private readonly XmlWriterSettings _xmlWriterSettings;

    public FileWriter(string localDirectory)
    {
        _localDirectory = localDirectory;

        _xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
            Encoding = _idTechConfiguration.Encoding
        };
    }

    public string Execute(RequestConfig requestConfig, XElement content)
    {
        var xmlDirectory = Path.Combine(_localDirectory, "xml");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(xmlDirectory);

        var filePath = Path.Combine(xmlDirectory, GetFileName(requestConfig));
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, _xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            content.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
        }

        return filePath;
    }

    private string GetFileName(RequestConfig requestConfig)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}_{4}.xml",
            requestConfig.ApplicationName,
            requestConfig.RequestType,
            requestConfig.UserData, 
            DateTime.Now.AsYyyyMmDdDashed(), 
            DateTime.Now.AsHhMmSsDashed());
    }
}
```